# Trying to integrate redux into react application. Webpack is choking on store.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, babeljs

I'm trying to integrate redux into an existing react application. All of my react code is within jsx files. Now i'm introducing redux and a store.js. during the compilation webpack errors on an exepected token error on store.js

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'project/static/public/js');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'project/static/public/js/components');


module.exports = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/App.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
    }
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel',
        presets : ['es2015']
      },
      {
        test : /\.js/,
        include : BUILD_DIR,
        exclude : /bundle.js||bundle.js.map||node_modules/,
        loader : 'babel',
        presets : ['es2015']
      }
    ]
  },
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true
  }

};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "start": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
      ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions", { "spec": true }],
      ["transform-class-properties"]
    ]
}
```

**store.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import combineReducers from './reducers/index.js'


export default createStore(combineReducers)
```

**error message**

> ERROR in ./project/static/public/js/store.js
>   Module parse failed: /home/username/git/project/project/static/public/js/store.js Line 1:
>
> Unexpected token
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | import { applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
>   | import combineReducers from './reducers/index.js'
>   | 
>    @ ./project/static/public/js/components/App.jsx 15:13-32

These files have gone through multiple iterations in trying to resolve and better understand redux. I think the problem is with my webpack configuration.

Comment: For `.js` files, you're only including `BUILD_DIR`. Where is `store.js` located? I'm guessing it's under `APP_DIR` and since it's not included in the config for `babel-loader`, Webpack doesn't know what loader to use.

Comment: store.js is in the root of `BUILD_DIR`. `project/static/public/js/store.js`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Babel are you using? I guess that you need to use the babel-loader in the webpack rule. This configuration works fines with Babel 7 and Webpack 4.

WEBPACK RULE:

```js
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include : BUILD_DIR,
        exclude : /bundle.js||bundle.js.map||node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
```

And .babelrc file example:

```js
{
  "presets": [[
    "@babel/preset-env", {
      "useBuiltIns": "entry"
    }],
    "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

Please, keep in mind you need to install babel-loader at least version 8.0.0, babel core 7.0.0 and webpack 4.23.

But, I'm pretty sure that the problem is that you need to use the babel-loader plugin in webpack. Visit https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Best!